# How to include data source in underscore template inside text/html?

Tags: underscore.js

Here's my code

```
<script type="text/html" id='usageList'>
            <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='1' >
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>LastName</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    /* I want to include data source via ajax or some mechanism here */
                    <%_.each(items,function(item,key,list){ %>
                    <% var f = item.name; %><!-- create more variables -->
                    <% var l= item.lastName; %>
                    <tr>
                        <!-- use variables -->
                        <td><%= key %></td>
                        <td class="<%= f %>"><%= f %></td>
                        <td class="<%= l %>"><%= l %></td>
                    </tr>
                    <% }); %>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get the template into a variable

```
var template = ​$(​'#usageList')​​​​​​​​​​​​​​.html();
```

Then, make an Ajax request. Using the `_.template` process the data received and add it to a DOM node

```
$.getJSON('ajax/test.json', function(data) {
    $('#output').html(_.template(template,{items:data}));
});
```

Data returned must follow this format

```
[
    {'name':'john', 'lastName':'M'},
    {'name':'jean', 'lastName':'N'},
    {'name':'carl', 'lastName':'K'},
    {'name':'peter', 'lastName':'B'}
]
```

Check this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jaimem/2gPYZ/